# How to add decorative borders in LibreOffice Writer?

Tags: libreoffice

I want to add decorative borders in LibreOffice writer ([like these](http://www.pdclipart.org/thumbnails.php?album=81) ) but I can't find this option anywhere. Below is a screenshot of this option in MS Writer:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I googled and found this comment on their independent QA site:

Defining Graphics or Colors in the Background of Pages (Watermark)
1. Choose Format - Page.
2. On the Background tab page, select a background color or a background graphic.

Edward (May 22 '13)

See also:
[This](https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/Background) and [that](https://help.libreoffice.org/Writer/Changing_Page_Backgrounds).
manj_k (May 22 '13)